# How to perform Hartley's test in R

Tags: r, testing, statistics, variance

I can find zero information on this. So if you have a web link or just know how to do it in R please let me know.

Here is the one-way anova example from some stats text book:

```
summary(av1)

            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
station      3 1479.2  493.07  4.1218 0.02412 *
Residuals   16 1914.0  119.63                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the package [SuppDists](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SuppDists/index.html) will be useful for you.

See [the documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SuppDists/SuppDists.pdf) (PDF) for *maxFratio*, which is another term for Hartley's test.